# Create dynamic visio diagram from Data

Tags: visio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb9Yb.png)

Is it possible to dynamically generate the diagram in picture with the data available in the accompanying table?
 Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Well, technically yes, it is possible. What kind of help are you looking for?

Comment: Honestly? Everything :D I need a way to create diagrams when people fill in the tables. I looked at VBA but it's way past my current knowledge.